# Data is being shown multiple times

Tags: mysql

I am having only one record under the `cust_vend_relation`

But its being displayed two times.

### **QUERY**

```
select cvr.customer_id,
cvr.address_label, 
cvr.vendor_name, 
cvr.vendor_id, 
vhd.locality, 
vhd.area, 
vhd.address,
vhd.city, 
vhd.state 
from cust_vend_relation cvr, vendor_home_delivery vhd
where cvr.vendor_id = vhd.vendor_id 
and cvr.address_label = 'Office' 
and cvr.customer_id = 3;
```

### **[This is my sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/172c0f/1)**

I need to show only the records present under the table `cust_vend_relation`  that matches with the records present under the `vendor_home_delivery`.

could anybody please help me .

Comment: Because you have 2 rows in `vendor_home_delivery` with vendor_id 1

Comment: But i need the record based on cust_vend_relation  table .

Comment: As you have 2 records in vendor_home_delivery , but you want only 1 record. So is there any criteria on which you will select only 1 record out of those 2?

Comment: Does not matter since there are 2 records in the `vendor_home_delivery` table for `vendor_id = 1` and joining the tables will yield 2 records. All you can do a group by at the end `group by cvr.customer_id`

Comment: You have 2 entries of 2 different area as "Near Cyinet" & "Raheja Mndspace". So which record you want to select out of them?

Comment: You've got multiple options:
1) Remove "vhd.address" from your select, and add "DISTINCT" right after "SELECT";
2) or add "GROUP BY 1" at the end of your sql;
3) or remove duplicate id from vendor_home_delivery;

Answer (score 0):

Add Group By customer_id

```
select 
cvr.customer_id,
cvr.address_label, 
cvr.vendor_name, 
cvr.vendor_id, 
vhd.locality, 
vhd.area, 
vhd.address,
vhd.city,
vhd.state 
from cust_vend_relation cvr, vendor_home_delivery vhd
where cvr.vendor_id = vhd.vendor_id and cvr.address_label = 'Office' and cvr.customer_id = 3 group by customer_id;
```